# how do i code for RadioButton and CheckBox to insert Data into Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have Write This Code. But now i don't have any idea to write code for radio button and Checkbox. Pleas Help.

"Gender" is a Radio Button.
"Vaccinated is a CheckBox"

```
    private void buttonprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into birth values(@applicanturdu,@applicantname, @applicantnic,@childurduname,@childname,@rishta,@relation,@gender,@cast,@sibling,
@religion,@walidname,@fathername,@fathernic,@walidaname,@mothername,@mothernic,@dadaname,@grandfather,@dadanic,@birthzilla,@birthdistrict,@birthdate,@vaccinate,@birthplace,@doctor,@disability,@education,@village,@uc,@vc,@tehsil,@district)";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@applicanturdu", textBoxapplicanturdu.Text));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@applicantname", textBoxbachaname.Text));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@applicantnic", textBoxapplicantnic.Text));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender");
           command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Vaccinated");
```

Comment: What are the SQL types of Gender and Vaccinated columns in your Database?

Comment: you see how you are adding to the other paramaters like @applicatnname, textBoxachaname. the textboxachaname is text box you need to do the same fro the radio button and the checkbox. It has been a while since I done winforms but I think you are just missing that and maybe .value at the end. You are not far off

Comment: Sql Data Type is (nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read the value of the Checkbox and the value of the radio buttons.

It is best to let your form have a separate procedure for it.

```
private MyForm()
{
     InitializeComponents();

     // put the value of the gender radio buttons in the Tag
     gender1.Tag = Gender.Male;
     gender2.Tag = Gender.Female;
     gender3.Tag = ...;
}
```

Methods to read the items that the user selected:

```
private Gender ReadGender()
{
    // find which radio button is checked:
    Gender selectedGender = GenderRadioButtons
        .Where(radioButton => radioButton.IsChecked)
        .Select(radioButton => (Gender)radioButton.Tag)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    return selectedGender ?? Gender.Unknown;
}

private bool IsVaccinated
{
    return this.checkBoxVaccinatated.IsChecked();
}
```

The procedure to add a Birth Object from the items that the operator selected:

```
private void AddBirth()
{
     using (var dbConnection = ...)
     {
         dbConnection.Open();
         using (var command = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
         {
             command.CommandText = ...
             command.Parameters.Add(...);
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", this.ReadGender());
             command.Parameters.Add(..., this.IsVaccinated);
             ...
          }
    }
}
```

Finally your Button event handler:

```
private void OnButtonAddBirthClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AddBirth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your field for gender and vaccinated in your table is a boolean then these parameters will do:
`command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", radioButton1.Checked);` 
`command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Vaccinated" checkBox1.Checked);`

Answer (score -1):

Add this below html in your .aspx file or where ever you wanna place the radio buttons.

```
 <div>
   <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Male" GroupName="gender"/>  
   <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Female" GroupName="gender" /> 
<asp:Label runat="server" id="genderId"></asp:Label><br /> 
</div>
```

In your .cs File under this button click event just place this under below code so

```
private void buttonprint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            genderId.Text = "";  
            if (RadioButton1.Checked)  
            {  
                genderId.Text = "Your gender is "+RadioButton1.Text;  
            }  
            else 
            {
            genderId.Text = "Your gender is "+RadioButton2.Text;  
            }
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", genderId.Text);
   }
```

Please use this code as per your need, this is just for the Radio Button and for check box you have to mentioned what are value you need to use then i migth help you. Hope this this will resolve your half question.

Comment: winforms isn't a web forms application all he needs to do is get the name in the properties of the checkbox and the radio buttons. Yes he can add a if statement but he needs to add those to his parameters like he did the other things.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I Have Check Box. Name Vaccinate. one is Yes and The Other is No. One will be Checked and other will be remain unchecked

Comment: @josh, i just have given him the example how he can achieve this. i just given him the way so he could make little effort to achieve this, hope that make sense.thanks for giving negetve reveiws.

Comment: @AttaUrRahman, why do you need checkbox if you need to select only one option at a time, if you just need one value at a time like yes or no then you should go for radio button as did for gender one value at time. if you have other requirement so please post  more specifically. thanks

Comment: ok Sir. But i have another Checkbox Also Disability. No, Deaf, Mental Disorder, Physical Disorder and Other. I want to check two or more at a time.

Comment: @AttaUrRahman, please give me sometime will send you the rest of the check box code.